# How to get the text inside single quotations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What formula can I apply to get what's inside single quotations and after a slash?

For example, I want to get only the names from the **Folder** column and put it in my **Names** column

[image]

It's a little hard because it's inside a single quote, this is what I'm applying but it's not working:

```
=MID(LEFT(A3,FIND("' ",A3)-1),FIND("/",A3)+1,LEN(A3))
```

Thanks

Comment: I want to confirm will the `My sister 'users/` will be consistent? If so then can we try this `=TEXTSPLIT(A2:A5,{"My sister 'users/","'"},,1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TEXTBEFORE()/TEXTAFTER()`.

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A2:A5,"/"),"'")
```

For excel ***2013 to 2021*** can use `FILTERXML()`.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"'",""),"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

And for all version of excel, try-

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"'",""),"/",REPT(" ",999)),999))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `TEXTAFTER()` & `SUBSTITUTE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(A2:A5,"/"),"'",)
```

---

Another way for older versions: using `REPLACE()` & `SUBSTITUTE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A2:A5,1,FIND("/",A2:A5),""),"'",)
```

---

Lot of ways to do this, here is another approach: Using `RIGHT()`, `FIND()` & `SUBSTITUTE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2:A5,LEN(A2:A5)-FIND("/",A2:A5)),"'",)
```

---

Comment: Just another alternative: `=TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"'","/"},,1),,-1)`

Comment: @JvdV Sir, just saw. sorry for the delay. May I add this in the post.